# Azure AD Premum

Tags: azure-active-directory

Our client wants to migration 50,000 external users (guest accounts - Microsoft accounts) into its Azure AD directory. They already have about 300 internal users (sourced from local AD) in the directory using Office 365. They would really like to brand the login pages for a good external users sign-in experience however this seems to be an Azure AD premium (basic edition) feature. As there will be 50k external users i.e. Microsoft Accounts (guest accounts) in the directory their is a big concern over the price around this. E.g. £0.74p x 50000 = £37,000 per month. This seems crazy and we were thinking surely can't be right? Is it possible to provide some guidance clarity this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer:  Yes, licenses (Premium or Basic) is required for users to access Premium/Basic features.  The B2B licensing model for premium functionality is *slightly* different.  It's a 1:5 ratio for Premium features. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-licensing).

**Per documentation:**
Company branding is a feature that is available only if you upgraded to the Premium or Basic edition of Azure Active Directory, or are an Office 365 user. For more information, see Azure Active Directory editions.
Azure Active Directory Premium and Basic editions are available for customers in China using the worldwide instance of Azure Active Directory. Azure Active Directory Premium and Basic editions are not currently supported in the Microsoft Azure service operated by 21Vianet in China. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding)